# Find LAN's IPv6 multicast address (or else all currently responsive LAN members)

Tags: ipv6, ping

Is there a way to see which devices (IP numbers) are active on the LAN over IPv6? With IPv4 I'd ping the broadcast address, which is usually not hard to determine.

With IPv6 I understand there are no more broadcast addresses but multicast addresses apparently play the same role. So how does one determine which address that is on the LAN behind a regular ISP's modem/router?

Comment: "_With IPv4 I'd ping the broadcast address, which is usually not hard to determine._" You mean the `255.255.255.255` Limited Broadcast address that is available on every LAN? Also, not all hosts respond to broadcast pings, regardless of IP version. Some do not even respond to unicast pings.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more googling I found [the answer](https://superuser.com/questions/840767/ipv6-multicast-address-for-all-nodes-on-network):

```
> ping6 -I <interfacename> ff02::1
```