# Find LAN's IPv6 multicast address (or else all currently responsive LAN members)?

Tags: linux, windows, domain-name-system

**Hi**

Is there a way to see which devices (IP numbers) are active on the LAN over IPv6? With IPv4 I'd ping the broadcast address, which is usually not hard to determine.

With IPv6 I understand there are no [more broadcast addresses](https://pmkisanbeneficiarylistwb.in/) but multicast addresses apparently play the same role. So how does one determine which address that is on the LAN behind a regular ISP's modem/router?

Comment: odd - **excatly** the same question asked (and self answered( 8 hours before this one ... https://serverfault.com/questions/1137038/find-lans-ipv6-multicast-address-or-else-all-currently-responsive-lan-members - identical - are you two doing the same exam?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find LAN's IPv6 multicast address (or else all currently responsive LAN members)](https://serverfault.com/questions/1137038/find-lans-ipv6-multicast-address-or-else-all-currently-responsive-lan-members)